# asp.net mvc 2 Htmlhelper collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui, collections, html-helper

Does anybody know a helpful collection of HtmlHelpers for Asp.Net MVC 2 for jQuery-UI Plugins?

I often use the jqGrid Plugin and found a nice HtmlHelper at http://www.webpirates.nl/webpirates/robin-van-der-knaap/47-fluent-jqgrid-html-helper-for-aspnet-mvc. Now I am looking for similar Helpers.

To write my own HtmlHelper Extensions is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Fluqi](http://fluqi.apphb.com), it pretty much builds everything for you with minimum effort required.